# How to decrypt a locally stored key as secure as possible

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I have a key I need to use in an application. That key has to be stored on the device in a persistant manner. I need to recover this key without using outside input like a user password. Any authentication that needs network/server connection (apart from authenticating the initial system logon with Active Directory) is not usable for me here.

Now, for decrypting any encrypted data myself, I would need a decrypted private key, which has to be stored somewhere again, and I'm unsure of the best practice here.

What would be the most secure ways to store and decrypt said keys using .NET in Windows 7?

Comment: If you can't take user input in any form then you have no choice but to use predefined fixed key. Using predefined fixed key is, generally speaking, the same as storing clear-text/unencrypted data in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Credential Vault through  `CredRead` and `CredWrite` with P/Invoke. It is specific to the user being logged or impersonated and does not require a password to decrypt.

Here's a sample from one of my deployment tasks, an example of how to securely retrieve a password for impersonation that is only accessible by the user task is being run under. It can be set through `control /name Microsoft.CredentialManager`, or through `cmdkey /?`, or through `CredWrite`.

```
private Task Impersonate()
{
    if (As == null)
        return this;
    Log.Debug("[As] {0}", As);

    IntPtr token;
    if (!CredRead(As, 1, 0, out token))
        throw new Win32Exception();

    var cred = (Credential)Marshal.PtrToStructure(token, typeof(Credential));
    CredFree(token);

    var name = cred.UserName.Split('\\');
    var user = new { Name = name[1], Domain = name[0], Password = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(cred.CredentialBlob) };
    Log.Info("[As] {0}\\{1}", user.Domain, user.Name);

    if (!LogonUser(user.Name, user.Domain, user.Password, 9, 0, out token))
        throw new Win32Exception();

    Context = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token);

    if (!CloseHandle(token))
        throw new Win32Exception();

    return this;
}

[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CredRead(string target, uint type, uint flags, out IntPtr credential);

[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern void CredFree(IntPtr buffer);

[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool LogonUser(string username, string domain, string password, int type, int provider, out IntPtr token);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

private struct Credential
{
    #pragma warning disable 169, 649
    public uint Flags;
    public uint Type;
    public string TargetName;
    public string Comment;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastWritten;
    public uint CredentialBlobSize;
    public IntPtr CredentialBlob;
    public uint Persist;
    public uint AttributeCount;
    public IntPtr Attributes;
    public string TargetAlias;
    public string UserName;
    #pragma warning restore 169, 649
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DPAPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/05/05/126825.aspx) should help you to encrypt and decrypt your key transparently